# The Texture is gone in the rendering

Tags: rendering, reflection

I am very new to Blender.

My texture/material is gone in the render result.

[image: How it should look]

[image: How it rendered]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your object looks like it's metallic and really glossy, assuming that, wha you don't have is an Image reflection (HDRI) like in the Shader View. But if that's not your case, please add more details about your Material settings

Comment: Hey thank you it worked with a hdri file